# Slicing and Assignment

Tags: python, function, numpy, slice, variable-assignment

I have to write a function that, given an array (A) and 2 numbers (X and Y, with X <=Y), subtract 3 from every element of array A within the restrictions of X and Y.
For example, given A = [1, 4, 9, 7, 5, 9], x = 3, and y = 8, the function should return:

```
[1, 1, 9, 4, 2, 9].
```

Here is my code so far:

```
def subtract_bw_elements(A,x,y):

    values_in_between = my_array[(my_array > x) & (my_array < y)] - 3

    return values_in_between

my_array = np.array([1, 4, 9, 7, 5, 9])
final_array = subtract_bw_elements(my_array,3,8)

print(final_array)
```

When I run this, I get this output:

```
[1,4,2]
```

Essentially, I'm able to get a sequence of values that are subtracted by 3. How do I input this sequence back into my original array? I believe I have to use assignment, but I don't really know how.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

You can use boolean filters to select the elements, then update them as you wish, e.g.:

```
A = np.array([1, 4, 9, 7, 5, 9])
x = 3
y = 8
cond1 = (A > x)
cond2 = (A < y)
A[cond1 & cond2] -= 3
```

output:
`array([1, 1, 9, 4, 2, 9])`

### performance

If it's just as easy to write performant code, do it - you will need it sooner or later.  Here is an example of the performance for a vectorized vs list-comprehension solution of 1M elements:

```
def func_vectorized(A, offset=3, x=3, y=8):
    cond1 = (A > x)
    cond2 = (A < y)
    A[cond1 & cond2] -= offset
    return A

def func_comprehension(A, offset=3, x=3, y=8):
    values_in_between = [i - offset if x<i<y else i for i in A]
    return values_in_between

# initialize array with one million elements
A = np.random.randint(0,20,1000000)
A1 = A.copy()

# compare performance of functions above using ipython `%timeit`:

%timeit func_vectorized(A)
# 911 µs ± 61.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit func_comprehension(A1)
# 838 µs ± 58.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

On my machine, the vectorized solution is about 500 times faster than the list comprehension.

Comment: using `*` is cryptic, it is more clear to use the boolean `&` like the OP is doing already

Answer (score 1):

you can simply achieve this by using list comprehension and if else check below example:

```
def subtract_bw_elements(A,x,y):

    values_in_between = [i - 3 if x<i<y else i for i in A]

    return values_in_between

my_array = [1, 4, 9, 7, 5, 9]
final_array = subtract_bw_elements(my_array,3,8)

print(final_array)
```

output is

```
[1, 1, 9, 4, 2, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```py
import numpy as np

def subtract_bw_elements(A,x,y):
    return [val-3 if val > x and val < y else val for val in A]

my_array = np.array([1, 4, 9, 7, 5, 9])
final_array = subtract_bw_elements(my_array,3,8)

print(final_array)
```

Output: `[1, 1, 9, 4, 2, 9]`

Note:

In your function you are using the variable `my_array`, but you have created the argument `A` that contains the exact same values, use `A`

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension. Iterate over `A` and `return` new list as per your need:

```
def subtract_bw_elements(A: list, x, y):
    return [x if x not in range(3, 8) else x-3 for x in A]

print(subtract_bw_elements([1, 4, 9, 7, 5, 9], 3, 8)) # [1, 1, 9, 4, 2, 9]
```